# Finding first derivative using DFT in Python

Tags: python, fft, derivative

I want to find the first derivative of `exp(sin(x))` on the interval `[0, 2/pi]` using a discrete Fourier transform. The basic idea is to first evaluate the DFT of `exp(sin(x))` on the given interval, giving you say `v_k`, followed by computing the inverse DFT of `ikv_k` giving you the desired answer. In reality, due to the implementations of Fourier transforms in programming languages, you might need to reorder the output somewhere and/or multiply by different factors here and there.

I first did it in Mathematica, where there is an option `FourierParameters`, which enables you to specify a convention for the transform. Firstly, I obtained the Fourier series of a Gaussian, in order to see what the normalisation factors are that I have to multiply by and then went on finding the derivative. Unfortunately, translating my Mathematica code into Python thereafter (whereby again I first did the Fourier series of a Gaussian - this was successful), I didn't get the same results. Here is my code:

```
N=1000
xmin=0
xmax=2.0*np.pi
step = (xmax-xmin)/(N)
xdata = np.linspace(xmin, xmax-step, N)
v = np.exp(np.sin(xdata))
derv = np.cos(xdata)*v
vhat = np.fft.fft(v)
kvals1 = np.arange(0, N/2.0, 1)
kvals2 = np.arange(-N/2.0, 0, 1)
what1 = np.zeros(kvals1.size+1)
what2 = np.empty(kvals2.size)
it = np.nditer(kvals1, flags=['f_index'])
while not it.finished:
    np.put(what1, it.index, 1j*(2.0*np.pi)/((xmax-xmin))*it[0]*vhat[[int(it[0])]])
    it.iternext()
it = np.nditer(kvals2, flags=['f_index'])
while not it.finished:
    np.put(what2, it.index, 1j*(2.0*np.pi)/((xmax-xmin))*it[0]*vhat[[int(it[0])]])
    it.iternext()
xdatafull = np.concatenate((xdata, [2.0*np.pi]))
what = np.concatenate((what1, what2))
w = np.real(np.fft.ifft(what))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data',0))
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax.spines['left'].set_position(('data',0))

plt.plot(xdata, derv, color='blue')
plt.plot(xdatafull, w, color='red')
plt.show()
```

I can post the Mathematica code, if people want me to.

Comment: Please remove `Solved` fro  your title, and post the solution you found as a proper answer.

Comment: Done, but how would people know that it is solved?

Comment: That is a good question! You can [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/), but there is a waiting period to prevent abuse. Then your question will be marked "has an accepted answer" just like any other.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I thought that accepting  my own answer will be cheeky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the problem is that `np.zeros` gives you an array of real zeroes and not complex ones, hence the assignments after that don't change anything, as they are imaginary.

Thus the solution is quite simply

```
import numpy as np

N=100
xmin=0
xmax=2.0*np.pi
step = (xmax-xmin)/(N)
xdata = np.linspace(step, xmax, N)
v = np.exp(np.sin(xdata))
derv = np.cos(xdata)*v
vhat = np.fft.fft(v)

what = 1j*np.zeros(N)
what[0:N/2.0] = 1j*np.arange(0, N/2.0, 1)
what[N/2+1:] = 1j*np.arange(-N/2.0 + 1, 0, 1)
what = what*vhat
w = np.real(np.fft.ifft(what))

# Then plotting
```

whereby the `np.zeros` is replaced by `1j*np.zeros`